# Using Nokogiri in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have the code that I need to do all the scraping and then printing the results to the console, but, I am confused about how to use it in an app.

The way it's supposed to work is through the `list#new` action I take user input for one parameter, `:url`. This URL is then passed to the scraping code, which obtains all the additional parameters and adds everything to Postgres tables. Using all of this newly acquired data, a new `list` is rendered.

The questions that I have:

1. the lists controller:

   ```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
     .
     .
     .
     def create
       @list = List.new ( #what goes in here? 
                          #only one param comes from the user
       if @list.save
         #how to set it up so that the save is successful 
         #only if the extra params have been scraped?
     .
     .
     .
   ```
2. I assume this will go into the models/list.rb:

   ```
   class List < ActiveRecord::Base

   require 'open-uri'

   url = #assuming that the url is proper and for something this code is supposed to scrape
         #is it better to add the url to db first or send it straight from the input 
         #and how is that defined here
   doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
   .
   .
   .
   ```

Could you give me some guidance here, please?

---

The services file:

```
class ScrapingService

  require 'open-uri'
  require 'nokogiri'

  def initialize(list)
    @list = list
  end

  url = :url
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  name = doc.at_css(".currentverylong").text
  author = doc.at_css(".user").text

  def scraped_successfully?
    if name != nil && author != nil
      true
    else 
      false
    end 
  end

  private

    attr_reader :list

end
```

Some questions that I have are:

1. How do I properly introduce `:url` into `HTML(open...`? The way I have it now throws `no implicit conversion of Symbol into String` error.
2. The part where `:url` along with `:name` and `:author` are supposed to be saved into one db entry is really murky.

Any article suggestions on this stuff are always welcome.

Comment: Is a List created regardless of the scraping? or do you need the scraping in order to save a list?

Comment: Later on, I'm will make some checks for whether the url submitted is valid (the page that opens is scrape-able with the code). So no, if no additional params can be retrieved through scraping, a new list entry will not be saved.

Comment: See my answer below. This is a rough estimation as to what it is you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**app/controllers/lists_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @list = List.new(list_params)
    if @list.save
      redirect_to @list
    else
      render :new
    end

  private

  #Assuming that you are using Rails 4 or the strong_params gem
  def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:url) 
  end
end
```

**app/models/list.rb**

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  # This runs only when you try to create a list. If you want to run this
  # validation when the user updates it, the remove the on: :create
  before_validation :ensure_website_is_scrapable, on: :create

  private

  def ensure_website_is_scrapable
    if ScrapingService.new(self).scraped_successfully?
      true
     else
      errors.add(:url, 'The website is not scrapable')
    end
  end
end
```

**app/services/scraping_service.rb**

```
class ScrapingService
  def initialize(list)
    @list = list
  end

  def scraped_successfully?
    # Do the scraping logic here and return true if it was successful or false otherwise
    # Of course split the implementation to smaller methods
  end

  private

  attr_reader :list
end
```

Comment: Awesome, I think is what I'm looking for. It will take me a few days to fill in all the blanks and get it up and running, because I'm still a beginner, but I will go ahead and check this one off.

Comment: Just ping me if you need anything, I will be glad to help.

Comment: Ok, I haven't managed to move much further forward. I updated the original post. Any suggestions of what I specifically need to read up on a welcome.

Comment: Create a private github gist and send me the link here so we can discuss it privately.